Is it possible that a non-Jew could have a Jewish soul?
Some people feel a deep and inexplicable connection to Judaism, something that seems to go above nature, perhaps related to a past life or other metaphysical cause. Is there any basis in Jewish teachings for such feelings being authentic, and what could be the ramifications of such feelings?

Many converts I've spoken to and read up on have made claims of having always felt strangely connected, or even Jewish. There are possibilities mentioned in some sources including if someone actually is Jewish but it's been forgotten in the family line, or they are a soul of someone who did accept the Torah when it was offered to the nations, and have had to make their way "in" (reincarnation etc), or they are a soul created by Avraham and Sarah in the years they were infertile. The best thing for you to do is find an Orthodox Rav to discuss this with, rather than here as it's quite personal

After conversion, converts are frequently told: You were with us at Sinai, remember?  (And he is supposed to answer: NOW you tell me!)

As the question stands, it might get closed, as asking for a practical ruling is against guidelines. I suggest removing the the last line ("and how should I approach this?")

According to the Arizal (one of our biggest kabbalists) in Shaar HaGilgulim (his book on reincarnation, some non-Jews are born with a "nefesh haGer" (the "soul of a convert") which is neither Jewish nor non-Jewish, but has the potential to become Jewish. This could well be your case

This asking for practical advice, not practical ruling. Is this on-topic?

Yes it's possible but it cannot be known unless this person accepts all aspects of Judaism and converts according to the torah's laws. See here... https://youtu.be/xZdFVKccpQU?si=73VxMpQJDY7Y9Rvc

Thats where the term גר שנתגייר from,   as opposed to גוי שנתגייר. Acc to kabalistic explanations, since he already had neshama of ger.
